# Compilation error: Conversion from CSV to Libsvm format

Tags: c++, c, matlab, csv, libsvm

I'm trying to convert à CSV training set to Libsvm format, using the **Libsvmwrite.c** file in matlab directory.
During the compilation, i got this error:
`bestmod@hadoopmaster:~/Downloads/libsvm-3.21/matlab$ gcc '/home/bestmod/Downloads/libsvm-3.21/matlab/libsvmwrite.c'
/home/bestmod/Downloads/libsvm-3.21/matlab/libsvmwrite.c: In function ‘libsvmwrite’:
/home/bestmod/Downloads/libsvm-3.21/matlab/libsvmwrite.c:29:2: error: unknown type name ‘mwIndex’
  mwIndex *ir, *jc, k, low, high;`
I checked well the code, but there is no problem with it.

Anyone have an idea about this issue ?
Regards

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please.

Answer (score 0):

OK

Here is my case:
i downloaded the dataset (training and test set) from the UCI, here is the link:
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/
And i changed the extension name of adult.data and adult.test to CSV 
Then i used the libsvm package that i got from the Libsvm web page

Besides, i followed an answer from an FAQ (How to convert other data formats to Libsvm format), using the libsvm package:
https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f307

In the extracted libsvm directory:
During the compilation of **libsvmwrite.c** from the matalb directory, it required three **h** files **mex.h** ,**matrix.h**, and **tmwtypes.h**, in order to solve some other compilation issues met.

After that, i got the problem cited above.
In **libsvmwrite.c**, i see no problem with mwIndex while it is defined:

`typedef int mwIndex;`

That's it, i hope my explanation is clear, and i appreciate your help.